# Optimizing a script which handles excel data

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

**Problem:** on and off 503 error on server.

**Hosting** said "you may need to optimize your application"

**Application:** built with CakePhp, running on php8, mysql

**What does the application do:**
process hundreds of rows of excel data (for logistic application).
at any one point, several locations may upload excel worksheet into the system to do content update. Excel sheet can contain 100-500 rows.
Some user will run into error 503.

**Advice needed.**
What can i do to optimize a script that performing such high load task?

Comment: Disconnect the uploading from the processing. That means you can process data sequentially, without overloading the server.

Comment: Remember we are not clairvoyant! And we are not looking over your shoulder.

Comment: Do you dump the data to a csv file, then use `LOAD DATA`?  Or do you "upload" some other way?